# upload file to server php

Tags: php, ftp

I already found many answer about this and here is what I used maybe you can find whats wrong

```
$target_file = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
$remote_file = "/mj/web/uploads/images/" . $target_file;  

$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.myftp.com") or die("Error in FTP connection");  
$login_status = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "pwd") or die("Error in FTP login");  

$upload_status = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $target_file, FTP_BINARY);

if (!$upload_status){
    echo "file not uploaded ";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I think the problem is in the path here is the error that it prints but i just couldn't find the right way, I tried many things

```
Warning: ftp_put(11896002_949007031828196_4852185396683089816_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/44/d426574394/htdocs/maisonstunisie/insertmj/config.php on line 72
```

file not uploaded

Here is the HTML form added as asked:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
        Titre Annonce :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ID="titre_annonce"  name="titre_annonce" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Description annonce :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ID="desc"  name="desc" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td> Photo :</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You are trying to upload file using connecting FTP data? why?

Comment: include your HTML form - and not in comments, but in your question as an edit.

Comment: This `"/mj/web/uploads/images/"` use a system path `/homepages/44/d426574394/htdocs/...` and make sure that folder has proper permissions to write to it.

Comment: Could you provide the code of ftp_put?

Comment: No comments from OP. My span of attention has expired and have since moved on. Good luck.

Comment: @anirudha i tried using 

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"] ["tmp_name"],"/mj/web/uploads/images/" . $_FILES["photo"] ["name"]);
 and i had the same error.

Comment: @fred-ii yes i tried this   
/homepages/44/d426574394/htdocs/mj/web/uploads/images/ 
and i also had the same error. 
sorry for late reply

Comment: @Wavemaster im sure that the paramaters to ftp_put are right i tested it